# Serial number in Django admin list view

Tags: python, django

I have the following list view in Django admin. How do I show serial number for every entry? Meaning numbering the list given in the list below. Also, this serial number should also take into account the pagination of the list.

[image]

Here is the model:

```
class Staff(User):
    INITIALS = (
        ("MR", "Mr."),
        ("MRS", "Mrs."),
        ("MS", "Ms."),
    )
    initials = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=INITIALS,
        default="MR"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.initials+" "+self.first_name+" "+self.last_name

    # Control model features
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Staff'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Staff'
```

Here is the admin model:

```
@admin.register(Staff)
class StaffAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_form = StaffCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name','institute','groups')
        }),
    )
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','password','groups','institute')}),
    )
    list_filter = ('institute',)
    inlines = [
        SubjectTeacher
    ]
    list_display = ("first_name", "last_name")
    list_per_page = 5
```

Comment: what you mean by `serial number`?

Comment: Like one, two, three etc for all respective entry shown in the model view

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a "serial number" field in your **Staff** model but I believe you are referring to its id

in your admin model you should be able to just include id to add the "serial number"

```
@admin.register(Staff)
class StaffAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_form = StaffCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name','institute','groups')
        }),
    )
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','password','groups','institute')}),
    )
    list_filter = ('institute',)
    inlines = [
        SubjectTeacher
    ]
    list_display = ("first_name", "last_name", "id")
    list_per_page = 5
```

Comment: I don't think I'm still clear. Basicially the serial number refers to numbered bulleting (eg: 1. Student one 2. Student two etc). This cannot really be done on model level because if I delete a student in future, that serial no will also be deleted. Hope now I'm clear as to what I need

Comment: I believe I can make this change in the template. The only gripe is that I'm unable to find the exact template I need to override.

Comment: Why not add a serial number to the staff model? What are you trying to accomplish with it

Comment: Like I said, I can't mention it in the model because if a record gets deleted, the serial number will be too

Answer (score -1):

In the list view you also need to include the serial number. You should share with us how you are expressing this view in code, instead of the screen shot to clarify the question

Comment: If you could share the model and your admin model this would greatly help. Generally you would just add the desired field to the admin model shown here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: Despite the fact that you can't leave comments yet (I guess), Zaraki Kenpachi already asked what serial number means and soner or later OP will need to show models. There is no need to leave a comment in answers.

Comment: I have added the model and admin model in my question

Comment: appreciate it mithil